# Could we merge two tags together.

Tags: support, tags

The tags `optimization` and `optimizations` are candidates for merging in my opinion.  There is only a handful of questions under each of them but having them both splits searching and browsing results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out. I have merged them.